# How to property call component inside same component using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a sidebar menu with submenu levels, and I'm using this code to build the menu and the submenus:

**Sidebar menu:**

```
import React from 'react';

import SidebarMenuItem from './SidebarMenuItem';

var menuData = require("./data/menu.json");

class SidebarMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = { expanded: true };
    };


  render() {

      return (
        <div>
          {
            menuData.map((item, index) => <SidebarMenuItem id={ index.toString()} key={index.toString()} {...item} />)
          }
        </div>
      );
  };
}

export default SidebarMenu;
```

**SidebarMenuItem:**

```
import React from 'react';

class SidebarMenuItem extends React.Component {

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.id);

        return (
            <div>
                <a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.title}<i className={'fa ' + this.props.icon}/></a>

                {this.props.submenu ? this.props.submenu.map((subitem, index) => <SidebarMenuItem key={this.props.id + index.toString()} {...subitem} />) : null }

            </div>
            )
    }

}

SidebarMenuItem.propTypes = {
    id: React.PropTypes.string,
    key: React.PropTypes.string,
    title: React.PropTypes.string,
    ref: React.PropTypes.string,
    icon: React.PropTypes.string,
    submenu: React.PropTypes.array
}

export default SidebarMenuItem;
```

Although I can see the submenus on screen, I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: SidebarMenuItem: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.
```

Another clue that something is wrong is the console output:

```
0
1 
undefined <-- I was supposed to get 11 and 12 here, as this option has 2 submenus
2
```

And finally my menu.JSON data:

```
[
  { 
    "title": "Option1",
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "icon": "fa-edit"
  },
  {
    "title": "Option2",
    "link": "",
    "icon": "fa-hello",
    "submenu": 
    [
      {
        "title": "SubOption2.1",
        "link": "wwww.yahoo.com",
        "icon": "fa-asterisk"
      },
      {
        "title": "SubOption2.2",
        "link": "wwww.tisafe.com",
        "icon": "fa-save"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Option3",
    "link": "www.mezasoft.com",
    "icon": "fa-save"
  }
]
```

Help appreaciated to find out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: You can't have a prop named 'key'. This name is reserved for react internal use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the warning because key is a restricted attribute and cannot be passed as a prop, change it to `keyValue`. Also you get `undefined` when you use `this.props.id` because in your `SidebarMenuItem render function` for submenus you are still calling the same component and there you are not passing the `id` as a `prop`. you can see that in the snippet below. I hope it helps

```js
class SidebarMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = { expanded: true };
    };


  render() {
      var menuData = [
  { 
    "title": "Option1",
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "icon": "fa-edit"
  },
  {
    "title": "Option2",
    "link": "",
    "icon": "fa-hello",
    "submenu": 
    [
      {
        "title": "SubOption2.1",
        "link": "wwww.yahoo.com",
        "icon": "fa-asterisk"
      },
      {
        "title": "SubOption2.2",
        "link": "wwww.tisafe.com",
        "icon": "fa-save"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Option3",
    "link": "www.mezasoft.com",
    "icon": "fa-save"
  }
];
      return (
        <div>
          {
           menuData.map((item, index) => <SidebarMenuItem id={ index.toString()} keyValue={index.toString()} {...item} />)
          }
        </div>
      );
  };
}

class SidebarMenuItem extends React.Component {

    render() {

        console.log('in render',this.props);

        return (
            <div>
                <a href={this.props.link}>{this.props.title}<i className={'fa ' + this.props.icon}/></a>

                {this.props.submenu ? this.props.submenu.map((subitem, index) => <SidebarMenuItem keyValue={this.props.id + index.toString()} {...subitem} />) : null }

            </div>
            )
    }

}

SidebarMenuItem.propTypes = {
    id: React.PropTypes.string,
    keyValue: React.PropTypes.string,
    title: React.PropTypes.string,
    ref: React.PropTypes.string,
    icon: React.PropTypes.string,
    submenu: React.PropTypes.array
}

ReactDOM.render(<SidebarMenu/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```